# How to fully manage ML Lifecycle in git for reproducible

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

All components of the end to end machine learning life cycle including data preparation steps, data clean, training model code, models and more want to be stored and version controlled in Git.

Can you please share the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Machine Learning Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-ml-pipelines) support everything. Further along the deployment and scale maturity level, use Kubeflow+MLflow to manage the scheduling of jobs. Both are open-source, platform and framework agnostic.

[image]

[Azure MLOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-model-management-and-deployment) provides comprehensive ML lifecycle management.

[MLOps Happy Path](https://github.com/Microsoft/MLOps): happy path for MLOps - end-to-end solution,

[Azure pipelines + ML CLI/MLOps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-azureml) Example Azure (DevOps) pipeline that uses ML CLI

Kubeflow Labs:  https://github.com/Azure/kubeflow-labs

Answer (score 0):

Our team does this by:

1. Use the SDK and Azure ML Pipelines to encapsulate all code and artifact creation within the pipeline control plane
2. Use [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org/) to coordniate artifact registration with feature branch names.

The Azure ML MLOps team also has [this repo](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython) which provides more info on step 1.